# Use Kotlin's `when` to pattern-match against an empty array?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Given `a` is an array, I'd like to use pattern matching to find out whether `a`'s an empty array. From other functional languages, I would assume that there exists some literal, e.g., `[]`, that represents an empty array, and I can just match against it, like so:

```kotlin
val a: Array<Int> = ...

when (a) {
    []   -> println("empty")
    else -> println("not empty")
}
```

Is this possible in Kotlin?

Comment: Why you do not use ˜isEmpty˜ function? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-empty.html

Your code doesn't compile because the ˜[]~in "when expression" is not allowed.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could use `println("empty" if (a.isEmpty()) else "not empty")`.

Comment: @Slaw do you wanna say: println(if (a.isEmpty()) "empty" else "not empty")

Comment: @PeterR Yes. Sorry, apparently I was somewhat in Python mode.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of `when` expression.

- `when` with a subject (which is in parentheses) can only be used with branches where the conditions are implicit `==`, `in`/`!in` something, or `is`/`!is` something.
- `when` without a subject allows each branch to be an arbitrary conditional.

The problem with arrays is that they have no useful `==` check. `arrayOf(1) == arrayOf(1)` will evaluate to false because they aren't the same array instance. This is one of several reasons you should usually prefer Lists to Arrays.

So, to handle an empty array, you have to use `when` without a subject:

```
when {
    a.isEmpty() -> println("empty")
    else -> println("not empty")
}
```

or in this particular case, you could move the empty check into the subject:

```
when (a.isEmpty()) {
    true -> println("empty")
    false -> println("not empty")
}
```

Comment: No reason to use a "when expression" in a non exhausts conditions.. in this case most recommend is to use a simple "if expression"..

Comment: Not sure what you’re getting at. This is an exhaustive condition. And `when` is appropriate for non-exhaustive situations to avoid else-if chains.

Comment: a simple ˜true/false" condition is not an exhaustive condition..

Comment: Disagree, it exhaustively covers all possible values of a Boolean, so you don’t need an `else` branch. But that’s not what you were getting at anyway. Yes, I agree if/else is usually preferable to when on a Boolean. I was only including it to explain all the available options with when, since that’s what the OP was asking about.